# CSS borders drawn over floated div

Tags: html, css

In the site I'm making I'm adding a feature that adds bulletins, little staff notices, at the top of the home page.  My idea was that I have a profile section floated to the left, a little dateline at the top showing (of course) the date, and some tags.

The problem arises with the dateline section.  The dateline is to the right of the profile at the top of the bulletin.  There is a border-bottom for the dateline, and this border stretches all the way across the bulletin, being drawn over the floated div.

I made an example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zVYuk/1/), you can see the problem.  For some background info, all bulletins will be inside the div.bulletin_frame, the "main div" if you will.  Within that there will be div.bulletin s.  I have it configured so that they all have a solid border at the top except for the first one, so that there's a border between them all. (see the stylesheet)

Thanks!

CSS:

```
div.bulletin_profile
{
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;

    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
    border-right: 1px gray solid;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
div.bulletin_dateline
{
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: monospace;
    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
}
div.bulletin_body
{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot of how you would like it to look? It's a little difficult to understand exactly what you need.

Comment: Doug: I just wanted the border to not be drawn in/through the profile section, James' answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The borders aren't drawn *over* the `div`, they're *behind* it. The divider simply has no background.

To change this, simply add a background to `.bulletin_profile`:

```
div.bulletin_profile {
    background:rgb(240,240,240);
}
```

Comment: Oh, well that's... I never would have thought of that haha.  Thanks!